# Replace single quotes with double with exclusion of some elements

Tags: python, regex, replace, nlp

I want to replace all single quotes in the string with double with the exception of occurrences such as "n't", "'ll", "'m" etc.

```
input="the stackoverflow don\'t said, \'hey what\'"
output="the stackoverflow don\'t said, \"hey what\""
```

Code 1:(@https://stackoverflow.com/users/918959/antti-haapala)

```
def convert_regex(text): 
     return re.sub(r"(?<!\w)'(?!\w)|(?<!\w)'(?=\w)|(?<=\w)'(?!\w)", '"', text)
```

There are 3 cases: ' is NOT preceded and is NOT followed by a alphanumeric character; or is not preceded, but followed by an alphanumeric character; or is preceded and not followed by an alphanumeric character.

Issue: That doesn't work on words that end in an apostrophe, i.e. 
most possessive plurals, and it also doesn't work on informal 
abbreviations that start with an apostrophe.

Code 2:(@https://stackoverflow.com/users/953482/kevin)

```
def convert_text_func(s):
    c = "_" #placeholder character. Must NOT appear in the string.
    assert c not in s
    protected = {word: word.replace("'", c) for word in ["don't", "it'll", "I'm"]}
    for k,v in protected.iteritems():
        s = s.replace(k,v)
    s = s.replace("'", '"')
    for k,v in protected.iteritems():
        s = s.replace(v,k)
    return s
```

Too large set of words to specify, as how can one specify persons' etc.
Please help.

**Edit 1:**
 I am using @anubhava's brillant answer. I am facing this issue. Sometimes, there language translations which the approach fail. 
Code=

```
text=re.sub(r"(?<!s)'(?!(?:t|ll|e?m|s|d|ve|re|clock)\b)", '"', text)
```

Problem:

In text, 'Kumbh melas' melas is a Hindi to English translation not plural possessive nouns.

```
Input="Similar to the 'Kumbh melas', celebrated by the banks of the holy rivers of India,"
Output=Similar to the "Kumbh melas', celebrated by the banks of the holy rivers of India,
Expected Output=Similar to the "Kumbh melas", celebrated by the banks of the holy rivers of India,
```

I am looking maybe to add a condition that somehow fixes it. Human-level intervention is the last option.

**Edit 2:**
Naive and long approach to fix:

```
def replace_translations(text):
    d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
    words=tokenize_words(text)
    punctuations=[x for x in string.punctuation]
    for i,word in enumerate(words):
        print i,word
        if(i!=len(words) and word not in punctuations and d.check(word)==False and words[i+1]=="'"):
            text=text.replace(words[i]+words[i+1],words[i]+"\"")
    return text
```

Are there any corner cases I am missing or are there any better approaches?

Comment: The mechanics of finding characters have nothing to do with language. For this reason, you might be mistaken to think you can do this with regex.

Comment: @sln I put a [non-regex answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32035513/2327328) but everyone was laughing at me :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### First attempt

You can also use this regex:

```
(?:(?<!\w)'((?:.|\n)+?'?)'(?!\w))
```

[DEMO IN REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/rG6gN0/3)

This regex match whole sentence/word with both quoting marks, from beginning and end, but also campure the content of quotation inside group nr 1, so you can replace matched part with `"\1"`.

- `(?<!\w)` - negative lookbehind for non-word character, to exclude words like: "you'll", etc., but to allow the regex to match quatations after characters like `\n`,`:`,`;`,`.` or `-`,etc. The assumption that there will always be a whitespace before quotation is risky.
- `'` - single quoting mark,
- `(?:.|\n)+?'?)` - non capturing group: one or more of any character or
  new line (to match multiline sentences) with lazy quantifire (to avoid
  matching from first to last single quoting mark), followed by
  optional single quoting sing, if there would be two in a row
- `'(?!\w)` - single quotes, followed by non-word character, to exclude
  text like "i'm", "you're" etc. where quoting mark is beetwen words,

### The s' case

However it still has problem with matching sentences with apostrophes occurs after word ending with s, like: `'the classes' hours'`. I think it is impossible to distinguish with regex when `s` followed by `'` should be treated as end of quotation, or as or `s` with apostrophes. But I figured out a kind of limited work around for this problem, with regex:

```
(?:(?<!\w)'((?:.|\n)+?'?)(?:(?<!s)'(?!\w)|(?<=s)'(?!([^']|\w'\w)+'(?!\w))))
```

[DEMO IN REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/rG6gN0/8)

[PYTHON IMPLEMENTATION](https://ideone.com/EDD2uD)

with additional alternative for cases with `s'`: `(?<!s)'(?!\w)|(?<=s)'(?!([^']|\w'\w)+'(?!\w)` where:

- `(?<!s)'(?!\w)` - if there is no `s` before `'`, match as regex above (first attempt),
- `(?<=s)'(?!([^']|\w'\w)+'(?!\w)` - if there is `s` before `'`, end a match on this `'` only if there is no other `'` followed by non-word
  character in following text, before end or before another `'` (but only `'` preceded by letter other than `s`, or opening of next quotaion). The `\w'\w` is to include in such match a `'` wich are between letters, like in `i'm`, etc.

this regex should match wrong only it there is couple `s'` cases in a row. Still, it is far from perfect solution.

### Flaws of \w

Also, using `\w` there is always chance that `'` would occur after sybol or non-`[a-zA-Z_0-9]` but still letter character, like some local language character, and then it will be treated as beginning of a quatation. It could be avoided by replacing `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)`  with `(?<!\p{L})` and `(?!\p{L})` or something like `(?<=^|[,.?!)\s])`, etc., positive lookaround for characters wich can occour in sentence before quatation. However a list could be quite long.

Comment: Definitely the way I'd go for it. Do consider replacing `[^']+` with `(?:[^']+|'\w)+`, to allow it to match "`'The Joneses' car won't start'`", assuming the added backtracking steps is not an issue here.

Comment: @Mariano thank you for a excellent hint! However I decided to put `\w'\w` instead of `'\w`, to include `'` in match, when it is between letters, but avoid matching `'` followed by letter, which should be the beginning of next quotation. It is a true backtracing monster, but problem is quite complicated. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
input="I'm one of the persons' stackoverflow don't th'em said, 'hey what' I'll handle it."
print re.sub(r"(?<!s)'(?!(?:t|ll|e?m)\b)", '"', input)
```

**Output:**

```
I'm one of the persons' stackoverflow don't th'em said, "hey what" I'll handle it.
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pE1iP1/3)

Comment: @anubhavaThanks! What about string possessive plural nouns like persons' etc.

Comment: Can you explain the use of `\b` here?

Comment: Great! Thanks. I am worked with look-arounds very less.  To add `(?<!s)` is this `re.sub(r"'(?!((?:t|ll|m|em)|(?<!s))\b)", '"', input)` correct?(added em for 'em)

Comment: I tried the adding `(?<!s)` but I am doing something wrong. Can you edit the answer to include it.

Comment: Thanks so much! One doubt   any reason you use  `e?m` instead of `em`.

Comment: Thanks! Great. Your answer seems to solve it perfectly! Do you think this expression would miss any corner cases? I am running on large text thus, it is a tough to check it manually if something is wrong.

Comment: It should work but I haven't seen your actual text so don't want to claim it will work with 100% of cases. But I think you get the idea. Even if you need to add more exceptions you can add them in lookahead or lookbehind using regex alternation.

Comment: Can you please check `edit 1` of the question. It seems to fail in a few cases. Please help if you can fix it. Thanks!

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: [You can use this](https://regex101.com/r/pE1iP1/5) but remember we don't have a way to differentiate between `melas'` and `persons'` in input.

Answer (score 6):

**Try this:**  you can use this regex `((?<=\s)'([^']+)'(?=\s))`  and replace with `"\2"`

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'((?<=\s)\'([^\']+)\'(?=\s))')
test_str = u"I'm one of the persons' stackoverflow don't th'em said, 'hey what' I'll handle it."
subst = u"\"\2\""

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

**Output**

`I'm one of the persons' stackoverflow don't th'em said, "hey what" I'll handle it.`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pE1iP1/4)**

Answer (score 4):

Here is a non-regex way of doing it

```
text="the stackoverflow don't said, 'hey what'"

out = []
for i, j in enumerate(text):
    if j == '\'':
        if text[i-1:i+2] == "n't" or text[i:i+3] == "'ll" or text[i:i+3] == "'m":
            out.append(j)
        else:
            out.append('"')
    else:
        out.append(j)

print ''.join(out)
```

gives as an output

```
the stackoverflow don't said, "hey what"
```

Of course, you can improve the exclusion list to not have to use manually check each exclusion...

Comment: The question's second tag is named `regex` :))

Comment: I know that this could be a valid solution, just that it was funny because of the irony.

Comment: Yep. I have a hobby of solving problems without regex :)

Comment: Interesting, I have a hobby of solving problems with regex :D

Answer (score 3):

Here is another possible way of doing it:

```
import re

text = "I'm one of the persons' stackoverflow don't th'em said, 'hey what' I'll handle it."

print re.sub("((?<!s)'(?!\w+)|(\s+'))", '"', text)
```

I have tried to avoid the need for special cases, it gives:

```
I'm one of the persons' stackoverflow don't th'em said,"hey what" I'll handle it.
```