# How to transform this text to json array formatted text

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains this:

```
{'text': 'today we will explore the culture of', 'start': 1.1, 'duration': 5.32}
{'text': 'them makkac we journey how do you say', 'start': 4.02, 'duration': 4.95}
{'text': "this one you think it's my now", 'start': 6.42, 'duration': 4.29}
{'text': "that's too long to be macaque maybe", 'start': 8.97, 'duration': 5.669}
{'text': 'Mecca Q o macaque alright Kashima island', 'start': 10.71, 'duration': 5.85}
```

and it needed to be converted to json array. I have this working code but i have many doubts if its the correct way to do it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = r"""{'text': 'today we will explore the culture of', 'start': 1.1, 'duration': 5.32}
{'text': 'them makkac we journey how do you say', 'start': 4.02, 'duration': 4.95}
{'text': "this one you think it's my now", 'start': 6.42, 'duration': 4.29}
{'text': "that's too long to be macaque maybe", 'start': 8.97, 'duration': 5.669}
{'text': 'Mecca Q o macaque alright Kashima island', 'start': 10.71, 'duration': 5.85}"""

    s = s.replace(r"{'text': '", r',{"text": "')
    s = s.replace(r"{'text': ", r',{"text": ')

    s = s.replace(r"', 'start':", r'", "start":')
    s = s.replace(r"'start':", r'"start":')

    s = s.replace(r"'duration':", r'"duration":')

    s = '[' + s[1:] + ']'

    print(s)
```

What is the recommended way of transforming it? I'm new to python by the way

Comment: There is the json module for python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json module is what you want; `json.loads(s)` in particular.

It’s not so simple however since your input data is not correctly formatted json. The single quotes for keys need to be double quotes and the array is not comma separated.

The code below gets around that

```
import re, json

string = r"""{'text': 'today we will explore the culture of', 'start': 1.1, 'duration': 5.32}
{'text': 'them makkac we journey how do you say', 'start': 4.02, 'duration': 4.95}
{'text': "this one you think it's my now", 'start': 6.42, 'duration': 4.29}
{'text': "that's too long to be macaque maybe", 'start': 8.97, 'duration': 5.669}
{'text': 'Mecca Q o macaque alright Kashima island', 'start': 10.71, 'duration': 5.85}"""

# regex replace single quote surround from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32529140/3959671
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:(?<!\w)\'((?:.|\n)+?\'?)(?:(?<!s)\'(?!\w)|(?<=s)\'(?!([^\']|\w\'\w)+\'(?!\w))))')
subst = u"\"\g<1>\""
result = re.sub(pattern, subst, string)

json_dict = [json.loads(x+"}") for x in result.split("}") if x]
```